# How can I iterate over each 2 consecutive characters in a string in go?

Tags: string, go

I have a string like this:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    some := "p1k4"

    for i, j := range some {
            fmt.Println()
    }
}
```

I want take each two consecutive characters in the string and print them. the output should like `p1, 1k, k4, 4p`.

I have tried it and still having trouble finding the answer, how should I write the code in go and get the output I want?

Comment: What should happen when your string contains multi-byte codepoints or invalid UTF-8? Unclear...

Comment: @jub0bs I read this question as a beginner go question (and clear enough) and not a request to find edge-cases.

Comment: @PaulHankin I understand this is a beginner question, but I still believe mine is a pertinent question. 1. We don't know where the input string comes from. Can we trust it to only contain ASCII? 2. Not covering all cases may introduce bugs. 3. Failed opportunity to learn how strings really work in Go.

Comment: @jub0bs a good way to provide such feedback is to write an answer that solves the simple case, and either expand the answer to one that works for all unicode (and invalid utf-8), or to discuss the deficiencies of your simple answer. A beginner asking a simple question in good faith is not likely to be able to have a meaningful discussion about edge-cases, important as we know they are. Sniping in comments (which to be fair, I've done more than my fair share of), is mostly unhelpful even if it's correct in an expert context.

Comment: @PaulHankin Apologies, I didn't mean to "snipe" at anybody. Conveying intent in written form can be difficult...

Comment: @PaulHankin let's assume good faith from all sides. About the question, the OP's code uses `range` so accounting for multi-byte chars is somewhat implied. I agree that a good answer should cover that, whether it was requested by the OP or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    str := "12345"
    for i := 0; i < len(str); i++ {
        fmt.Println(string(str[i]) + string(str[(i+1)%len(str)]))
    }

}
```

Comment: note that you can account for multi-byte characters, among others, by converting the input string to `[]rune` and applying this solution to that: https://go.dev/play/p/oJ1Y_ghYsoO

Answer (score 9):

Go stores strings in memory as their UTF-8 encoded byte sequence. This maps ASCII charactes one-to-one in bytes, but characters outside of that range map to multiple bytes.

So I would advise to use the `for range` loop over a string, which ranges over the runes (characters) of the string, properly decoding multi-byte runes. This has the advantage that it does not require allocation (unlike converting the `string` to `[]rune`). You may also print the pairs using `fmt.Printf("%c%c", char1, char2)`, which also will not require allocation (unlike converting `rune`s back to `string` and concatenating them).

To learn more about strings, characters and runes in Go, read blog post: [Strings, bytes, runes and characters in Go](https://go.dev/blog/strings)

Since the loop only returns the "current" rune in the iteration (but not the previous or the next rune), use another variable to store the previous (and first) runes so you have access to them when printing.

Let's write a function that prints the pairs as you want:

```
func printPairs(s string) {
    var first, prev rune

    for i, r := range s {
        if i == 0 {
            first, prev = r, r
            continue
        }
        fmt.Printf("%c%c, ", prev, r)
        prev = r
    }

    // Print last pair: prev is the last rune
    fmt.Printf("%c%c\n", prev, first)
}
```

Testing it with your input and with another string that has multi-byte runes:

```
printPairs("p1k4")
printPairs("Go-世界")
```

Output will be (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/p6TaYIKDOPR)):

```
p1, 1k, k4, 4p
Go, o-, -世, 世界, 界G
```

Comment: I can't help myself, the output can serve as the `prev` variable: https://go.dev/play/p/m_e66lVgMtg Very much this answer over indexing, though.

Comment: @Bracken Nice improvement, yes, it's a good idea to print the current rune so we can get rid of the `prev` variable.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple for loop over your string with the first character appended at the back:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    some := "p1k4"
    ns := some + string(some[0])
    for i := 0; i < len(ns)-1; i++ {
        fmt.Println(ns[i:i+2])
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this doesn't quite work because the example given in the question has the last entry wrapping round to the start: "4p".

Comment: @PaulHankin it works and you can try it here: https://go.dev/play/p/T1P_c0kcaHw

Comment: You're quite right, I'd missed that you'd appended the first char onto the end of the string.